# Create new column that returns the string that most frequently appeared in a selection of other columns in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count

I have a data frame (df) in r with 14 columns. In each of the rows those columns contain one of 13 strings or N/A.
So for example in one row only the first column has a value/string and the others are N/A and another has different as well as recurring values/strings in each of the 14 columns.
I now want to create a new (15th) column that would return the value/string that most frequently appeared in the other columns for that specific row. If strings appear the same number of times it should return the one that first appears in a column most to the left (i.e., lower column numbers in example below)

Here an example of what I mean by this.

What I have (except with 14 instead of just 5 columns):

```
  column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4  column_5 
1 Group A   Group D   N/A       N/A       N/A
2 Group B   Group B   Group A   N/A       N/A
3 Group F   Group A   Group B   Group B   N/A
4 Group C   Group A   Group C   Group A   N/A
5 Group E   N/A       N/A       N/A       N/A
6 Group A   Group A   Group A   Group B   Group B
```

What I would need the new column to look like:

```
  column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4  column_5  new_column
1 Group A   Group D   N/A       N/A       N/A       Group A
2 Group A   Group B   Group B   N/A       N/A       Group B
3 Group F   Group A   Group B   Group B   N/A       Group B
4 Group C   Group A   Group A   Group C   N/A       Group C
5 Group E   N/A       N/A       N/A       N/A       Group E
6 Group A   Group A   Group A   Group B   Group B   Group A
```

I have not tried any code yet, since I don't even know where to start... so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could first convert the `N/A` to `NA`

```
df1[df1 == "N/A"] <- NA_character_
```

Then, loop over the row, get the frequency count to return the names of the `max` frequency

```
df1$new_column <- apply(df1, 1, function(x)
   names(which.max(table(factor(x, levels = unique(x))))))
```

-output

```
> df1
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 new_column
1  Group A  Group D     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    Group A
2  Group B  Group B  Group A     <NA>     <NA>    Group B
3  Group F  Group A  Group B  Group B     <NA>    Group B
4  Group C  Group A  Group C  Group A     <NA>    Group C
5  Group E     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    Group E
6  Group A  Group A  Group A  Group B  Group B    Group A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column_1 = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group F", 
"Group C", "Group E", "Group A"), column_2 = c("Group D", "Group B", 
"Group A", "Group A", NA, "Group A"), column_3 = c(NA, "Group A", 
"Group B", "Group C", NA, "Group A"), column_4 = c(NA, NA, "Group B", 
"Group A", NA, "Group B"), column_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Group B"
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```